# What is the purpose of the Shinjuku Map item?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-4

One of the items released via QR codes for Etrian Odyssey 4 is called the "Shinjuku Map." However, I haven't found anywhere in the game that uses the map. Is it possibly for content that isn't released yet (maybe a free dungeon kinda like how Fire Emblem has some free areas)? Or does it serve some other purpose?

[Source](http://etrianodyssey4.blogspot.com/2013/01/this-is-test-post.html) (I just noticed the .html file name for that URL when I pasted it.. interesting. Related?)

Comment: No. If you notice that post was actually posted before the demo was release much to the confusion of everyone who was following it. They said they'd fix it but never did. It's not related at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sell it, it's worth 500. It serves no purpose really. Shinjuku is where the Atlus headquarters are, it's also a sort of joke towards the first game. Also, there are several other QR codes that you can find online that will give you other "Trade Items." They're all worth 500 and they're all useless as far as the game is concerned.